# validation failed for query and NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, jpa, tomcat

i have two classes "FicheBesoins" and "PlanFormationGeneral" with a relation @@ManyToOne, i would like to get "nom and "prenom" in  fiche,i've created a query in PlanFormationGRepository :

```
@Query("SELECT FicheBesoins.nom,FicheBesoins.prenom  FROM FicheBesoins  WHERE 
 PlanFormationGeneral.idplan=FicheBesoins.idplan" )
 public List<FicheBesoins> getFiches();
 }
```

FicheBesoins:

```
@Entity
public class FicheBesoins implements Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int id ;
private int matricule;
private String nom ;
private String prenom ;
private String emploi ;
private String filiere ;
private String tachePrincipale ;
private String DirectionAeroport ;
private String division ;
private String service ;
private int comptenceActuelleNA ;
private int competenceActuelleNR;
private int nouvellecompetenceNA ;
private int nouvellecompetenceNR;
private String theme ;
private String niveaudemande ;
private String typeformation ;
private String periode ;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="idplan")
private PlanFormationGeneral planFormationGeneral;

public FicheBesoins() {
    super();
}
public FicheBesoins(int matricule, String nom, String prenom, String emploi, String filiere, String tachePrincipale,
        String directionAeroport, String division, String service, int comptenceActuelleNA,
        int competenceActuelleNR, int nouvellecompetenceNA, int nouvellecompetenceNR, String theme,
        String niveaudemande, String typeformation, String periode) {
    super();
    this.matricule = matricule;
    this.nom = nom;
    this.prenom = prenom;
    this.emploi = emploi;
    this.filiere = filiere;
    this.tachePrincipale = tachePrincipale;
    DirectionAeroport = directionAeroport;
    this.division = division;
    this.service = service;
    this.comptenceActuelleNA = comptenceActuelleNA;
    this.competenceActuelleNR = competenceActuelleNR;
    this.nouvellecompetenceNA = nouvellecompetenceNA;
    this.nouvellecompetenceNR = nouvellecompetenceNR;
    this.theme = theme;
    this.niveaudemande = niveaudemande;
    this.typeformation = typeformation;
    this.periode = periode;
}

public FicheBesoins(int matricule, String nom, String prenom, String emploi, String filiere, String 
        tachePrincipale,
        String directionAeroport, String division, String service, int comptenceActuelleNA,
        int competenceActuelleNR, int nouvellecompetenceNA, int nouvellecompetenceNR, String theme,
        String niveaudemande, String typeformation, String periode, PlanFormationGeneral 
    planFormationGeneral) {
    super();
    this.matricule = matricule;
    this.nom = nom;
    this.prenom = prenom;
    this.emploi = emploi;
    this.filiere = filiere;
    this.tachePrincipale = tachePrincipale;
    DirectionAeroport = directionAeroport;
    this.division = division;
    this.service = service;
    this.comptenceActuelleNA = comptenceActuelleNA;
    this.competenceActuelleNR = competenceActuelleNR;
    this.nouvellecompetenceNA = nouvellecompetenceNA;
    this.nouvellecompetenceNR = nouvellecompetenceNR;
    this.theme = theme;
    this.niveaudemande = niveaudemande;
    this.typeformation = typeformation;
    this.periode = periode;
    this.planFormationGeneral = planFormationGeneral;
}
```

PlanFormationGeneral:

```
@Entity
public class PlanFormationGeneral  implements Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int idplan;
private String domaine;
private Date date ;
private String organismeformateur ;
private String depenseprevisionnelle ;
private int dureeJ;
private int dureeH;
@OneToMany( mappedBy = "planFormationGeneral",fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Collection<FicheBesoins> ficheBesoins;
```

when i run the project i got this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List org.sid.dao.PlanFormationGRepository.getFiches()!
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:93) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.<init>(SimpleJpaQuery.java:63) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromMethodWithQueryString(JpaQueryFactory.java:76) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromQueryAnnotation(JpaQueryFactory.java:56) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:140) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:207) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:78) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:574) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:567) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:569) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:559) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
at java.util.Optional.map(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:559) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:332) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:297) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:212) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:300) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:121) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at java.lang.String$CaseInsensitiveComparator.compare(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
at java.lang.String$CaseInsensitiveComparator.compare(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
at java.util.TreeMap.getEntryUsingComparator(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
at java.util.TreeMap.getEntry(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
at java.util.TreeMap.get(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
at org.hibernate.dialect.function.SQLFunctionRegistry.findSQLFunction(SQLFunctionRegistry.java:45) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.findSQLFunction(SessionFactoryHelper.java:385) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.IdentNode.getDataType(IdentNode.java:366) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.lookupProperty(HqlSqlWalker.java:667) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.propertyRef(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1154) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2315) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectExprList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2256) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1518) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:597) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:325) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:273) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:272) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:192) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:144) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:155) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:604) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:716) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:23) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:366) ~[spring-orm-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy85.createQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:87) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
... 63 common frames omitted
```

i've tried with this query but it seems that UNION dosen't work:

```
@Query("SELECT FicheBesoins.nom, FicheBesoins.prenom  FROM FicheBesoins LEFT 
Join PlanFormationGeneral ON PlanFormationGeneral.idplan=FicheBesoins.idplan 
UNION ALL SELECT FicheBesoins.nom, FicheBesoins.prenom FROM FicheBesoins 
RIGHT Join PlanFormationGeneral ON 
PlanFormationGeneral.idplan=FicheBesoins.idplan ")
```

any idea please!